# wrap python os.system method

Tags: python, wrapper, os.system

I have the following perl module for wrapping CORE::system in perl scripts:

```
package system_wrapper;

sub check_system {
    my ($cmd) = @_;

    my $err = CORE::system($cmd);
    if ($err != 0) {
        print "Error occured when executing: $cmd. Exiting.\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
}
*CORE::GLOBAL::system = \&check_system;

1;
__END__
```

I'm attempting to acheive the same thing in python. I can't work out how to extend the syntax described [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FunctionWrappers) using decorators to this os method.

I would like calls to the wrapped method to be exactly the same as the unwrapped.

i.e. `status = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")`

Comment: i missed something from this wrapper. `check_system` should return `$err`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just monkey patch `os.system`. Rename the real `os.system` to something else,
then create a function using it and assign it to `os.system`:

```
def my_os_system(cmd):
    err = os._system(cmd)
    if err != 0:
        print "Error occured when executing: %s. Exiting." % cmd
        sys.exit(-1)

os._system = os.system
os.system = my_os_system
```